# Two-phase commit vs Paxos

Tags: database, transactions, distributed-transactions, paxos, 2phase-commit

I am quite confused with these two technologies.

1. Are there any relationship between these two technologies
2. Are there any existing popular open source software implements these technologies? I know zookeeper implements Paxos but what about Two-phase commit?

Comment: You would improve this question by including references (URLs) for Paxos and 'zookeeper'.  The Paxos tag wiki gives a little information, but no URLs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paxos vs two phase commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304887/paxos-vs-two-phase-commit)

Comment: Zookeeper uses ZAB protocol http://goo.gl/p40YhP which they actively deny is Paxos http://goo.gl/WIymnn Read http://the-paper-trail.org/blog/consensus-protocols-paxos/ blog descriptions of 2pc, 3pc and Paxos to understand the differences. He also has a blog where we implements Paxos using Python

Comment: Many, many open source projects have implemented two-phase commit (2PC). Most multi-shard databases fall in this group. But most (I can't claim all) of them use 2PC tightly integrated inside their application, and not as an open source easily portable piece of code. Therefore, if your goal is just understand the protocol or simply contrast its implementation with Paxos in all failure paths, I suggest just search "two-phase commit" on Github or similar places.